# terminator intercepts F10 when run in openbox

Tags: terminal, openbox, gnome-terminator, gtk2

When I am in `openbox` and I start `terminator` and inside it `mc`, I cannot use <kbd>F10</kbd> to exit from `mc` because it is intercepted by `terminator` an terminator menu opens (same as right-mouse-click).

On [terminator forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/terminator/+question/176046) they suggest to add following into gtkrc:

```
binding "NoKeyboardNavigation" {
    unbind "<shift>F10"
}

class "*" binding "NoKeyboardNavigation"
```

This solves the problem in `LXDE`, when I add the above lines to

```
/usr/share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

But it does not solve the problem in `openbox`, even when I am using the same theme (Clearlooks).

I have also tried adding the lines to :

```
~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

but still no effect in `openbox`.

How can I fix this problem in `openbox` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard locations for gtk2 configuration files are

- `/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`: system wide
- `~/.gtkrc-2.0`: user specific

Thus, try to change one of those files instead of `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.

Actually there is some inconsistency, because `gtk3` is indeed using `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`, but that is another story.